# Having trouble with seaborn module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to draw some basic plots using the seaborn's `jointplot()` method.

My pandas data frame looks like this:

```
Out[250]:
YEAR    Yields  avgSumPcpn  avgMaxSumTemp   avgMinSumTemp
1970    5000    133.924981  30.437124   19.026974
1971    5560    107.691316  31.161974   19.278186
1972    5196    116.830066  31.454192   19.443712
1973    4233    181.550733  30.373581   19.097679
1975    5093    112.137538  30.428966   18.863224
```

I am trying to draw `'Yields'` against `'YEAR'` (So a plot to see how `'Yields'` is varying over time). A simple plot.

But when I do this:

```
sns.jointplot(x='YEAR',y='Yeilds', data = summer_pcpn_temp_yeild, kind = 'reg', size = 10)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-251-587582a746b8> in <module>()
      3 #ax = plt.axes()
      4 #sns_sum_reg_min_temp_pcpn = sns.regplot(x='avgSumPcpn',y='avgMaxSumTemp', data = df_sum_temp_pcpn)
----> 5 sns.jointplot(x='Yeilds',y='YEAR', data = summer_pcpn_temp_yeild, kind = 'reg', size = 10)
      6 plt.title('Avg Summer Precipitation vs Yields of Wharton TX', fontsize = 10)
      7 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.pyc in jointplot(x, y, data, kind, stat_func, color, size, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim, joint_kws, marginal_kws, annot_kws, **kwargs)
    793     grid = JointGrid(x, y, data, dropna=dropna,
    794                      size=size, ratio=ratio, space=space,
--> 795                      xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
    796 
    797     # Plot the data using the grid

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.pyc in __init__(self, x, y, data, size, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim)
   1637         if dropna:
   1638             not_na = pd.notnull(x) & pd.notnull(y)
-> 1639             x = x[not_na]
   1640             y = y[not_na]
   1641 

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not Series
```

So I printed out the types of each column. Here is how:

```
for i in summer_pcpn_temp_yeild.columns.values.tolist():
    print type(summer_pcpn_temp_yeild[[i]])

print type(summer_pcpn_temp_yeild.index.values)
```

which gives me:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

SO, I am not being able to understand how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the **YEAR** and **Yields** have *integer* ( not *string*) types of values.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing x='Yeilds' to x='Yields' in your call to jointplot:

```
sns.jointplot(x='YEAR',y='Yeilds', data = summer_pcpn_temp_yeild, kind = 'reg', size = 10)
```

The error message is misleading. Seaborn can't find the column named "Yeilds" in your summer_pcpn_temp_yeild dataframe, because the dataframe column is spelled "Yields".

I had the same problem, and fixed it by correcting the x= argument to sns.jointplot()